# Disable NeoComplCache based on filetype

Tags: vim, neocomplcache

I am trying to get vim setup such that when I edit a C or C++ file it uses the [YouCompleteMe](https://github.com/Valloric/YouCompleteMe) plugin for completions, and for everything else it uses [NeoComplCache](https://github.com/Shougo/neocomplcache).

I'm starting with v3.0 of the [spf13 vim configuration](https://github.com/spf13/spf13-vim).

I've added the following to my `.vimrc.bundles.local`:

```
Bundle 'Valloric/YouCompleteMe'
```

I've added the following to my `.vimrc.local`:

```
let g:ycm_filetype_whitelist = { 'c': 1, 'cpp': 1 }
let g:neocomplcache_force_overwrite_completefunc = 0
```

This appears to disable YouCompleteMe for everything except C/C++, however I'm not sure how to disable NeoComplCache based on filetype. I have tried:

```
autocmd FileType c,cpp :NeoComplCacheDisable
```

However, it appears that NeoComplCache isn't really enabled until you do something in the buffer. What kind of configuration is needed to disable NeoComplCache when I open a C or C++ file in vim?

Comment: What about `let g:neocomplcache_disable_auto_complete = 1`?

Comment: @romainl doesn't work. `completefunc=neocomplcache#manual_complete` after the first insert operation.

Comment: Now I remember why I decided to not use that plugin.

Comment: @alanxz: could you please post your final solution?

Comment: @BenC: terryma's solution didn't work because :NeoComplCacheLock doesn't restore the omnifunc and complfunc correctly. The solution I thought I had was to have this function call :NeoComplCacheDisable, but due to NCC's lazy initialization (it initializes on CursorHold and CursorHoldI) this doesn't work because NCC isn't enabled at that point.

Bottom line: still looking for solution.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's how I disabled NeoCompleCache for [my `.vimrc`](https://github.com/docwhat/homedir-vim/blob/master/vimrc/.vimrc):

```
" Disable NeoComplCache for certain filetypes
if has('autocmd')
  autocmd FileType pandoc,markdown nested NeoComplCacheLock
 endif
```

References:

- [NeoComplCache issue #352](https://github.com/Shougo/neocomplcache.vim/issues/352)

Answer (score 2):

This is what I use for editing markdown files, it should work c,cpp as well.

```
" Turn off completion, it's more disruptive than helpful
function! s:markdown_disable_autocomplete()
  if &ft ==# 'markdown'
    :NeoComplCacheLock
  endif
endfunction
autocmd MyAutoCmd BufEnter * call s:markdown_disable_autocomplete()
```

Comment: This didn't quite work, but it lead me down a path to make something that did work.

Comment: Check that - I didn't actually come up with a solution that worked.